# Issues in building BoneCP using maven

Tags: bonecp

I downloaded the latest BoneCP source code from following Github URL:

https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/archive/master.zip

When I try to build this source using maven there are some issues in compiling 
bonecp-hbnprovider module. Initially I was getting the following error:

*Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.jolbox:bonecp-parent:pom:0.8.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 19, column 13 -> [Help 2]*

After changing  *0.8.0-rc1-SNAPSHOT to  0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT* in the pom.xml of bonecp-hbnprovider I am getting the following error:

*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bonecp-provider: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.jolbox:bonecp-provider:bundle:0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT in spring-milestone (http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/milestone) -> [Help 1]*

Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What's the command you're using? Try with: mvn clean install